# How to extend validation rule only for some RuleSets

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a property of the model that must always follow some constraints. In case of some actions (e.g. adding) it must also create a unique key. I see no way without duplicating the basic rule to conditionally extend it with an additional constraint.

With FluentValidation I have built a Validator that has most of the Rules in the default (unnamed) RuleSet and some additional RuleSets including the "Adding". Wanted to call Validator with appropriate RuleSets to run depending on calling action (for add it would be "Adding" + default).
For the problematic property, let's say "PartialKey", I was thinking about using `When` but I haven't seen a place to take RuleSets which were passed at the validation call. Defining the rule in "Adding" `RuleSet` forces me to duplicate the basic part of the rule for "PartialKey" from the default `RuleSet`.

Simplified piece of code

```cs
public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        this.RuleFor(model => model.PartialKey).MustMeetBasicConstraints()
            .MustNotExistUniqueComposeKey()
            .When(() => executingRuleSets.Contains("Adding"), ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator);

        this.RuleSet("Adding", () =>
        {
            this.RuleFor(model => model.PartialKey).MustMeetBasicConstraints()
                .MustNotExistUniqueComposeKey();
        });
    }
}
```